# Modifying a Custom Element class after it's been defined

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component, custom-element

Is it possible to modify a custom element / web component class after it's been registered? This isn't something I'll typically (or ever) want to do in production code, but when prototyping or implementing a code-patching tool for development, it'd be useful. Here's what I've tried, unsuccessfully, so far:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('foo-bar')) // empty element

class FooBar extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback () {
    this.textContent = 'foo bar'
  }
}

customElements.define('foo-bar', FooBar) // element shows "foo bar"

FooBar.protoype.connectedCallback = function () {
  this.textContent = 'foo bar 2'
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('foo-bar')) // element shows "foo bar", not "foo bar 2"

customElements.get('foo-bar').protoype.connectedCallback = function () {
  this.textContent = 'foo bar 2'
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('foo-bar')) // element shows "foo bar", not "foo bar 2"

class FooBar2 extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback () {
    this.textContent = 'foo bar 2'
  }
}

customElements.define('foo-bar', FooBar2) // Exception thrown, 'foo-bar' already defined
```

In summation, modifying the class originally passed to the CustomElementsRegistry has no effect. Assigning to the prototype of what's in the registry has no effect. Attempting to assign a new class to the element in the registry isn't possible as an exception is thrown. All three of these behaviors are counter to my experience with almost every aspect of every other JavaScript API. It's extremely unusual, for better or worse, to not be able to mutate something unless it's set to be non-configurable. However, when I inspect if the objects are configurable, the runtime says they are!

Does anyone know of a way to modify/augment a custom element definition after it's been defined?

Comment: It seems that `customElements.define` obtains a reference to the various member functions of the provided class and trying to override those did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a very *rough* [prototype](https://github.com/zalari/custom-elements-loader-prototype/tree/develop) that allows you to `customElements.define()` CustomElements *multiple* times. This gives you the flexibility to overwrite any future usages of your custom element.

*Modifying* an existing *class* for a CustomElement has the disadvantage, that you would lose the mapping between the actual CustomElement and its actual class and that might be the reason, why it is not possible...

**With the above prototype implementation loaded**, you can do the following:

```js
// add <foo-bar> to the DOM
// define it once
customElements.define('foo-bar', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super() };
  connectedCallback() { this.textContent = 'foo bar'; }
}
// ...
// and define it again :)
customElements.define('foo-bar', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super() };
  connectedCallback() { this.textContent = 'foo bar 2'; }
}
// and add it <foo-bar> again to the DOM to get the new impl
```

Comment: Do you wrap `customElements` and delegate to it?

Comment: @james_womack In a nutshell yes, however the actual _trick_ is, that I generate CustomElements with an increasing index and they get defined via the usual CE API. Initially a _wrapper_ component is created that is using the current index via a closure. Just have a look at the source maybe yourself, it's _open_. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change a tag once defined, seems like it pulls in the class when defined.

I have found a way to dynamically reload the code behind a custom element by placing a wrapper class as the constructor, I now have hot reloading on custom elements, no more refreshing apps - the wrapper will need to handle attribute bubbling etc

basically you need to rely on the following pieces

1. knowing what elements are not defined, ideally called whenever you performing changes to the DOM, alternatively you could place a setInterval for development.
   `document.querySelectorAll(':not(:defined)')`
2. define the custom element inline so you can use the same constructor for ALL custom elements. `customElements.define(elementName, class extends HTMLElement {...`

---

```
document.querySelectorAll(':not(:defined)').forEach((ele, k) => {
        let elementName = ele.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (!customElements.get(elementName)) {

            //defining custom element
            customElements.define(elementName, class extends HTMLElement {
                constructor() {
                    super();
                }

                disconnectedCallback() {
                    if (this._elementClass) {
                        this._elementClass.disconnectedCallback()
                    }
                }

                connectedCallback() {

                    let element = (this.tagName).toLowerCase();

                    //reload the class variable here eg: importScript/getScripts 
                    //dependent on whatever variable you want eg: cache id or 
                    //then make calls to the customElement class
                    this._elementClass = new NodeTest(this);
                    this._elementClass.connectedCallback(); 


...


var NodeTest = class {

    constructor(ele) {
        this.ele = ele;
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {

    }

    connectedCallback() {

        this.render();
    }

    render() {
        this.ele.innerHTML = '<h1>hheee</h1>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented a [similar approach](https://github.com/zalari/custom-elements-loader-prototype/tree/develop), however not explicitly like you did, but implicitly by _monkey-patching_ `window.customElements`. That way it could at least in theory work with any CustomElement (although right now there are a lot of limitations).

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be hard to change a behaver of a tag, they(browser developer) might think one tag should only defined once.

I tested to modify shadow root, it worked, If you want to template your custom tag, shadow root will help.

```js
let customTable = document.registerElement('custom-table', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
    createdCallback: {
      value: function() {
        let shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
        window.shadowRoot = shadowRoot
        let template = document.querySelector('#custom-table');
        shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
      }
    }
  })
});

let i = 0
setInterval(() => {
  shadowRoot.append(`${i++}s past `)
}, 1000)
```

```css
table {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<template id="custom-table">
  <style>
    table {
    }
  </style>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>P</td>
        <td>P</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>P</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
<custom-table></custom-table>
<table>
</table>
```

Use MVVM is another option, they can also template things, but realtime modify may need manually trigger rerender

- angular (typescript,need compile)
- react (jsx, need compile)
- angular 1.x
- vue

Comment: Hey Josh. Thank you for your answer. What I'm asking is how to modify or replace the class / custom element definition behind the tag. Not how to modify the DOM inside of the tag's HTML on the page. I can always define a tag without a shadow DOM or with an open shadow DOM if I want to modify the HTML itself. If you look at my comments in the code of my question, I just want to be able to do what I'm saying there. Thanks again for your answer though :)

Comment: @james_womack as you already know our code run in broswer, alough W3C standard exists , still it's the browser developer decide what the result would be. Binding to another tag will work but I'm sure It's not what you want, so I guess you want to template some thing and template would change when you want to :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed this for hot reloading, I've got to a solution, but it uses clojurescript. In the end the code is compiled to javascript, so might be worth to take a look: https://clojureverse.org/t/hot-reloading-custom-elements-web-components/5964

Comment: Hot reloading is the reason I wanted to do this as well